# Analysis and n-adic expansions

Tags: analysis, terminology, decimal-expansion

I am trying to discern some mathematical term known as a $n$-adic expansion. For example the book I am reading says: write every $x  \in[0, 1]$ its "$4$-adic" expansion
\begin{equation}
   x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\dfrac{x_i}{4^i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k\dfrac{x_i} {4^i} + r_k(x)
\end{equation}
for $(x_i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}, 1 \leq i < \infty)$

Could someone explainwhat this $4$-adic expansion means and why it is useful? Every google result search brings up $p$-adic expansions where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: You probably have already encountered a "10-adic expansion": this is just decimal expansion of a real number. Here, a "4-adic" expansion is just writing number in base 4. The "n-adic expansion" is  a bad name, because it can easily lead to confusion with p-adic numbers, which are totally different beasts.

Comment: That's very strange use of $n$-adic, rather than "base $n$". Is this common? I usually take $n$-adic to mean something similar but completely different :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, although it's out of fashion. Consider "dyadic fraction" for example.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in comments: $n$-adic is sometimes used  as a synonym of "base $n$", although this use is old-fashioned and potentially confusing. These days one is more likely to hear *binary expansion* than *dyadic expansion*. Nonetheless, an interval of $\mathbb R$ formed by all numbers with a given initial segment of binary expansion is usually called a *dyadic interval*.